Animator does not have an AnimatorController error Unity C#
I'm trying to play an animation through script in Unity and whenever I call it it returns the error

Animator does not have an AnimatorController
UnityEngine.Animator:Play (string)

My animator has the animation controller referenced (even during runtime) and the animator seems to work fine with changing variables.
Here is the code:
player.am.StopPlayback();
player.am.Play(card.cardInfo.animation.name);

And here is the animator:
animator tree
If anyone could help that would be appreciated

can you share ? can you  show it during runtime? is that property unsetting itself, or the animator being removred and remade?

@BugFinder nothing happens to the animator during runtime, nothing is being disabled, its the same thing the entire time

I think you are trying to call function from another instance but to be sure we need to check your player spawn and animation player scripts. Also can you provide the hiearachy of objects and scripts?

Idk how to add images but I'll try and explain it best I can.
The hierarchy for my player is
PlayerHolder (contains UI script and CameraShake script)

CameraHolder (contains Camera)
Player (contains RB2D, Player Movement Script, Animator, Collider, and all the body parts of the character and child objects (which have no scripts) and the weapon.
UI (the health UI)

The player spawn script is just setting the position whether the player loaded in from a checkpoint or not, but the object is not instantiated on scene start.
Again my animator never changes on playtime, load, or exit

Why not use triggers as parameters and conditions to transition from Idle to the other states. Animator Controller is actually meant for that. If you have multiple animations which need to blend between them, have a look at blendtrees.

Well than how would I go back to idle from walking?
Also I plan on having lots of "pitchfork anims" (attacks) and would just like something thats easier to scale, I don't mind using triggers though, just wanted to see if there were other options

Maybe any state to each one of your clips. Also add transition time, so that it does not look wierd

I tried using triggers but it seems to never trigger :/
I'll have to do some debugging later

So I have a whole bunch of triggers set up from an "Any State" and then I have a bool that allows the animations to switch back to Idle. The problem is that none of the triggers are well, getting triggered, neither does the bool, and when I manually click the trigger it plays the animation but the trigger immediately resets. Idk if this means anything but I'm also setting the variables from a script not on the player, but I have made functions for that player allowing me to set the variables from inside the player script
